# Keep running until user enters q simple program flow

Tags: c

```
char buffer[50], x, a;
    int y,z;


    printf(">");
    fgets(buffer,50,stdin);
        if( 1 == sscanf(buffer,"%[Q]",&a) )
        {
            printf("quit");
        }

        else if( 1 == sscanf(buffer,"%d", &y) )
        {
            printf("Insert the number\n");
            insert(head,y);

        }
        else if( 2 == sscanf(buffer,"%[s] %d", &a, &z) )
        {
            printf("Search list for number\n");
            search(head,z);

        }
        else if( 2 == sscanf(buffer,"%[d] %d", &a, &y) )
        {
            printf("Need to delete number from list\n");

        }
        else if( 1 == sscanf(buffer,"%[p]",&a) )
        {
            printf("Print the list\n");

        }
        else if( 1 == sscanf(buffer,"%[?]",&a) )
        {
            printf("Help this dude\n");

        }
        else
        {
            printf("print error and show help message\n");


        }
```

The above code is going to be used in a simple linked lists program but I can't seem to grasp the flow through all these loops. the program should run until user enters Q

if they enter "Q" (without quotes), then exit the program;

if they enter a number (must be an integer), search the list for that number. If 
it's already in the list, tell the user and do nothing else; otherwise insert that number into the list (it doesn't matter where you insert it);

if they enter the command "s " followed by a number (with a space after s), search for that number, and tell the user whether that number is found in the list or not;

if they enter the command "d " followed by a number, search for that number in the list, and if you find it, delete it; otherwise tell the user that number was not found;

if they enter "p" then show them the entire list;

if they enter ? then show them a brief help message explaining the different command options;

otherwise print an error message, and show them your help message.

Thank you for the help

NOTE: this is not a complete program I have not implemented the linked list yet, which is why there are just print statements stating what needs to be done in each if loop

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to check `strcmp(buffer, "Q") == 0`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need the program to keep running until user enters q I tried putting all of this in a while loop but I couldnt get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[50], x, a;
    int  y, z;


    printf("> ");

    while (fgets(buffer, 50, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        if ( 1 == sscanf(buffer, "%[Q]", &a) )
        {
            printf("quit");
            return 0;
        }
        else if ( 1 == sscanf(buffer,"%d", &y) )
        {
            printf("Insert the number\n");
            insert(head, y);
        }
        else if ( 2 == sscanf(buffer,"%[s] %d", &z) )
        {
            printf("Search list for number\n");
            search(head, z);
        }
        else if ( 2 == sscanf(buffer,"%[d] %d", &a, &y) )
        {
            printf("Need to delete number from list\n");
        }
        else if ( 1 == sscanf(buffer,"%[p]",&a) )
            printf("Print the list\n");
        else if ( 1 == sscanf(buffer,"%[?]",&a) )
            printf("Help this dude\n");
        else
            printf("print error and show help message\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

note that this will also terminate if the user sends `EOF` to the terminal, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on linux or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on windows.

**Recommendation**: use

```
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
```

that way if you change the size of `buffer` you don't need to change the `fgets()` line.

Answer (score 0):

For your question:

> if they enter "Q" (without quotes), then exit the program;

```
fgets(buffer,50,stdin);
```

If the input is `Q` then there is a newline char in the buffer since you are using `fgets()` you need to supress/remove by replacing `\n` by `\0`.

Then you can do

```
if(strcmp(buffer,"Q") == 0 )
{
   printf("Quit\n");
   return 0; 
}
```